# Traveling through Canada on China Southern, in transit visa required while quarantined in the “sterile transit area”?

Tags: filipino-citizens

I’m a Filipino passport holder. No U.S. visa, no Canadian visa. I’m flying from Costa Rica to Mexico City. Then Mexico City to Vancouver, then to China, then Philippines.  I get on China Southern flight number 378 in Mexico City and it lands in Vancouver Terminal M.   The exact same flight number on China Southern 378 and Terminal M and even the same seat goes all the way from Vancouver to Guangzhou.   The stop in Vancouver is 1 hour 50 minutes. We have to get off the plane.  The Canadian website on in transit immigration is very unclear.   It says if you stopover on an international flight you will “stay in the sterile transit area” while you transition in the same flight like I will.    I take this to mean we get off the plane, stand around in the “sterile transit area” for no more than 1 hour 50 minutes and then we get back on the plane.  No special visa would be required, is this correct?  Has anyone done this?

Comment: Phillipine passport holders are eligible for the [Transit Without Visa program](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html), and China Southern is a participating airline, but this is only for transits to or from the US, which yours is not.

Comment: See http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/passenger-guides . You should be fine during "regular" hours, but not from 2am to 7am

Comment: @Hilmar Canada is in the process of building sterile transit areas in its major airports, but it has not yet updated its immigration laws to allow for visa-free sterile transit (except a few nationalities in a couple of pilot programs, which don't apply here). He will still need a visa despite the existence of the sterile transit area.